# Android SDK override AlertDialog events

Tags: android

I am instantiating an alert dialog like so:

```
AlertDialog myAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext).create();
```

Is there a way to override the `OnKeyDown` event for this dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AlertDialog.Builder build=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
build.setMessage("This is a message, dawg.")
.setPositiveButton("Awesomesauce.", new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
    {
        //stuff here
        dialog.dismiss(); //closes the window
    }
};
AlertDialog myAlert=build.create();
myAlert.show();
```

You can also add a `.setNegativeButton()` or `.setNeutralButton()` to change the neutral/negative buttons, too.

The Android SDK doc for it is [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html)